# How to add a node on a path edge in pylatex Tikz

Tags: tikz, pylatex

I'm able to create a path with the edge with

```
p1=TikZCoordinate(0,0)
p2=TikZCoordinate(2,3)

mypath=TikZPathList()
mypath.append(p1)
mypath.append('--')
mypath.append(p2)

tikz_code=TikZDraw(mypath)

tikz_code.dumps_as_content()

fig=TikZ()
fig.append(tikz_code)

print(fig.dumps_as_content())
```

which produce

```
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path[draw] (0.0,0.0) -- (2.0,3.0);%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I cannot add a node on the edge
`mypath.append('node[midway,above] {$a$}')` is an invalid coordinate string (accepting only '--' etc.)
Creating  a `TikzNode` doesn't work either.

Any suggestion?

I would like to achieve

```
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path[draw] (1.0,4.0) -- node[midway,above] {$a$} ++(4.0,-2.0);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

but I can't find a way to add the `node[midway,above] {$a$}` in my path.